# On composition of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Given two irreducible polynomials $f_{u}(x),f_{r}(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$, can one find two polynomials or rational functions $h_{u}(x),h_{r}(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ or $\Bbb Q(x)$ respectively such that:$$f_{u}(h_{u}(x)) = f_{r}(h_{r}(x))?$$

Comment: My brain is annoyed by your choice of notation!

Comment: @anon: what's not to like about the notation?  Clearly "r" stands for "right", and "u" stands for "left".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139648/on-composition-of-polynomials/139653?noredirect=1#comment360333_139653)  The upshot is that the answer is usually "no", and one can explicitly describe all $f_u$ and $f_r$ for which such $h_u$ and $h_r$ do exist.  The proof is very difficult, and among other things relies on the classification of finite simple groups.